# Deploy a website from Visual Studio to webserver

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm using a blank VS2010 solution to manage a static website I maintain. I was going to use the ASP.NET website project, but that added a bunch of stuff the webserver wouldn't do. If I should still use that project, please let me know!

I have the code under source control and try to have the DEV region in source mirror the DEV webserver. I want to migrate my changes to the dev server for others to view, but I'm not sure of the best method to do this. If I use the Publish Website command in VS, it will delete the files on the server and copy all the files. The problem with this is that it takes waaayyy too long. Especially when I am on the VPN. I could manually copy the files, but that's a sloppy way to do it. And the server doesn't have FTP so that's not an option either. Is there some blatant method I am missing?

I thought about setting up a workspace with the server as the working folder. Then, whenever I wanted to migrate a change, I'd just do a "get latest" in that workspace and it would bring down any files that have changed. Does this sound like an okay method or is there a preferred method for this?

Comment: "The problem with this is that it takes waaayyy too long."  Visual Studio does several things during a publish\deploy.  Which part in the process is taking "too long"?  Visual Studio may actually be building the application before deployment, so that is why it may take a while.

Comment: I'll need to check that, thanks Rami.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend against using web site "projects" for anything. Use a Web Application Project instead.

Secondly, when you use MSDEPLOY from the Publish command, it synchronizes the target web site with the source - it will only deploy changed content.

Comment: Should I use a Web Application Project even if it's just a static website on a server that doesn't support ASP.NET? I thought that when you do a Publish command, it deletes the files on the server first. At least that what it appears to be doing for me. Maybe I didn't set something right?

Comment: Yes, always use web application projects. They're like all other Visual Studio projects. Web site "projects" are weird - no project file, include all files that happen to be in the folder, etc. Even different publish options.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [copy/website functionality](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-deploy-a-web-site-using-the-copy-web-site-tool)

Comment: I've seen that option but I haven't checked it out yet. I'd like to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up a continuous integration server (ex. CruiseControl.NET).
2. Create a new build project for each website you wish to deploy, initially configured for manual invocation.
3. Configure the build project to do a get latest and deploy.

Here are some possible implementations:
http://callicode.com/Homeltpagegt/tabid/38/EntryId/27/How-to-only-publish-the-runtime-files-of-an-asp-net-application-using-CruiseControl-net.aspx
http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Build+Publisher

Comment: That's a great idea, but I'm unable to use a continuous integration server at the moment. I'd love to implement one though! It's on my list of TO-DO's.

Comment: You can install ccnet on your local machine.  That way, you can even skip the "get latest" part.